# Google only returns ID and picture of user

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am authenticating users through oAuth against Google as the IdP. I cannot, for the life of me, get Google to return anything but the ID and the picture url. I have requested the proper fields (email family_name, given_name, id), but I still only get back the ID and picture field.

I am using the "https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo" endpoint in a get request with the following query string values:

- state
- access_token
- fields(which are:  email family_name given_name id)
- key

What I get back is the unique ID and the path to the user's thumbnail photo, but I do not get the other scope items.

Get Request:

> https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo?state=MyUniqueValue&key=MyAPIKey&fields=email%2Cfamily_name%2Cgiven_name%2Cid&access_token=y26.bigrandomstring

I have also tried:

> https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo?state=MyUniqueValue&key=MyAPIKey&fields=email,family_name,given_name,id&access_token=y26.bigrandomstring

I even tried the deprecated, then de-deprecated endpoint with formfields:

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_token=y26.bigrandomstring&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me

No matter what I use, I still get back the same thing every time:

```
{
  "id": "1067xxxxxxxx50",
  "picture": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-7RzMk8xmlAg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/SfdfsdfsdfYaBtg/photo.jpg"
}
```

I even get the "200 OK" response. Any ideas?

Comment: You request user information via scopes during authentication which the user must approve.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was using the wrong endpoint and scope. The correct endpoint and scope were:

> https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=names,emailAddresses

As part of the request I have formfields of access_token and key (api key).