# Google API REST call return only user id and picture. How to get full user info with Google API REST requests?

Tags: api, rest, google-api, google-oauth, access-token

I try to access Google user info trough API request;

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=ya29.a0Ael9sCMYNzgxZT27Cb....
```

All I am getting for response is Id and profile pic:

```
{
    "id": "1.....",
    "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/ACB-R5Sg...."
}
```

I need more user info: email, name, etc.

I have added user.profile and userinfo.email and userinfo.profile scopes in developer console.

[image: scopes added]

I know added scopes can take 5mins-few hours to work but I added it ~12h ago.

How to fix my API REST call to get more user info from Google API?

EDIT

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153870/google-only-returns-id-and-picture-of-user) is same, but the answer didnt work for me. This request:

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=names,emailAddresses&access_token=ya29.a0...&key=498...apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Got me `Request had insufficient authentication scopes` error.

Maybe I am providing wrong key there? What should be api key then, its client id from credentials page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found my mistake. I wasnt providing a scope in the primary request. So actions to receive  google acccount info goes like this:

GET request:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
       scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile 
       https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email 
    &redirect_uri=https://www.youtube.com/
    &response_type=code
    &client_id=498...apps.googleusercontent.com
```

This code opened me a desired page (youtube in this case) after registration with code:

```
https://www.youtube.com/?
code=4%....
&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+openid
&prompt=consent
```

I copied given code to POST request:

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?
code=4%2...
&client_id=498....apps.googleusercontent.com
&client_secret=GO...
&redirect_uri=https://www.youtube.com/
&grant_type=authorization_code
```

And got:

```
{
    "access_token": "ya29....",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "id_token": "eyJhb...."
}
```

Now with final request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=ya29...
```

I receive more info:

```
{
    "sub": "10....",
    "name": "V....",
    "given_name": "V....",
    "family_name": "L....",
    "picture": "https....",
    "email": "vy...",
    "email_verified": true,
    "locale": "lt"
}
```

Comment: I was following this 
Houssem Dellai tutorial for the whole proccess if you need more info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgFIsVr26zg

Comment: Very Nice post. Very Helpful. Thank you.